# Why is "onmouseover" not working on a live website launched through Netlify?

Tags: image, onmouseover, netlify

I'm doing my first bit of coding in school, making a simple website. I code in Visual Studio Code and I'm using a mouseevent for pictures. I want the picture to change into another picture and then change back to the original pic when the mouse is hovering over it.

I've tried multiple different ways of doing this, including simple functions and more complex ones. All working perfectly on my live server version of the site. But as soon as I launch the site through Netlify, making it live, the mouse hover function ceases to work.

This is the current way I'm doing it, and as I said, works perfectly in VS Code:

```
<img src="assets/GrasshopperPapaya.jpg" height="550" width="700" onmouseover="this.src='assets/onionized-jungle-imagen.png'" onmouseout="this.src='assets/GrasshopperPapaya.jpg'"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the [same problem](https://google-glass-html5.netlify.app/index.html) using onmouseover and Netlify (while changing menu pictures when mouse moves over menu itens).

I don't know if that couldn't be a browser issue. On [this case](https://support.google.com/webdesigner/thread/230574?hl=en) the problem occurs using onmouseover, but only on Chrome.

Please, let me know if you find an answer.